# SQL find missing language entries in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which is missing some entries for a certain language. How can I get a list of all language text in english (lang 1 in table) which is missing the foreign translation counterpart (lang 2)

My table is as follows

```
PageName | LanguageNo | TranslationName | TranslationText   |
main     |     1      | SomeName        | some english text |
main     |     2      | SomeName        | some foreign text |
main     |     1      | SomeName2       | some english 2    |
other    |     1      | SomeName3       | some english 3    |
other    |     2      | SomeName3       | some foreign 3    |
```

For example, using the above table data, only the following should be returned:

```
main     |     1      | SomeName2       | some english 2    |
```

How can I write a SQL statement to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: First what DBMS are you using?? And second try something yourself and post the code if you don't succeed so people can debug on it.

Comment: Apologies my friend,  I am using T-SQL on MS SQL Management Studio.

Comment: LanguageNo and TranslationName are the keys?

Comment: The table is using PageName, LanguageNo anf TranslationName as a composite key

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've created an example code below - including input/output of the statement

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I went with Gordons solution.

Comment: But Gordon's solution does not match the sample.  There is pagename = main with a LanguageNo = 2 so it would return zero rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods, but here is one that uses `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.LanguageNo = 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from mytable t2
                  where t2.pagename = t.pagename and 
                        t2.translationname = t.translationname and
                        t2.LanguageNo = 2
                 );
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c771/2) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I'm prety sure that this won't give the desired result. I've tested it with the demo data given. (You can use my table structure in my answer to test it on your own)

Comment: Nice to help you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
-- Create demo data
CREATE TABLE #translation(pageName nvarchar(10), LanguageNo int, TranslationName nvarchar(25), TranslationText nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO #translation(pageName, LanguageNo, TranslationName, TranslationText)
VALUES  ('main',1,'SomeName','some english text'),
        ('main',2,'SomeName','some foreign text'),
        ('main',1,'SomeName2','some english 2'),
        ('other',1,'SomeName3','some english 3'),
        ('other',2,'SomeName3','some foreign 3')
        --,('other',3,'SomeName3','some foreign 3') -- uncomment for language3 demo

-- your work:
SELECT availTrans.*
FROM #translation t
-- get all needed combinations
RIGHT JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT t.pageName, t.TranslationName, langs.LanguageNo
        FROM #translation as t
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT LanguageNo FROM #translation) as langs
    ) as availTrans
    ON t.pageName = availTrans.pageName
    AND t.TranslationName = availTrans.TranslationName
    AND t.LanguageNo = availTrans.LanguageNo
WHERE t.pageName IS NULL

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #translation
```

Given input:

```
pageName   LanguageNo  TranslationName           TranslationText
---------- ----------- ------------------------- ---------------------
main       1           SomeName                  some english text
main       2           SomeName                  some foreign text
main       1           SomeName2                 some english 2
other      1           SomeName3                 some english 3
other      2           SomeName3                 some foreign 3
```

Which produces this result:

```
pageName   TranslationName           LanguageNo
---------- ------------------------- -----------
main       SomeName2                 2
```

Comment: At first I thought that this was over-complicated. Then I realised that it's the only solution that addresses finding missing translations when there are multiple "foreign" languages. Add some rows with LanguageNo=3 to see this.

Comment: I've added a language 3 to the demo which is by default commented out, due to the fact that the OP haven't provided it. Yes this solution works for an independent amount of languages. I'm pretty sure that the marked answer isn't the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tblTranslation t1
LEFT JOIN tblTranslation t2 ON t2.PageName = t1.PageName  
                            AND t2.TranslationName = t1.TranslationName 
                            AND t2.LanguageNo = 2
WHERE t1.LanguageNo = 1
AND t2.LanguageNo IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM tblTranslation t1
  LEFT JOIN tblTranslation t2 
    ON t2.TranslationName = t1.TranslationName        
   AND t2.LanguageNo = 2
 WHERE t2.TranslationName IS NULL
   AND t1.LanguageNo = 1
```

Comment: This returns everything with LanguageNo <> 1 as well.

Comment: See move t1.LanguageNo = 1 to where

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `SUM` with `OVER()` like this.

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT pageName, LanguageNo, TranslationName, TranslationText,
    SUM(CASE WHEN LanguageNo = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY TranslationName) L1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN LanguageNo = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  OVER(PARTITION BY TranslationName) L2
    FROM #translation t
)
SELECT pageName, LanguageNo, TranslationName, TranslationText FROM CTE
WHERE L1 >=1 AND L2 = 0
```

**Output**

```
pageName    LanguageNo  TranslationName TranslationText
main    1   SomeName2   some english 2
```

Comment: Yes, but beware that this will work only for 2 languages. It needs to be adapted if you have more languages over time :)